# How docker does load balancing between containers when using scale flag without using docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing, scale

I configured a docker compose file with two services : 1 node js app and 1 nginx as reverse proxy. I used docker compose scale flag to scale (3) the node container.

Some how docker is load balancing the traffic between 3 node containers but I'm not able to understand how and I could not find it in documentation either. Can you please help me understand it.
Note : I'm not using docker swarm.

This is the configuration I used in nginx

```
worker_processes auto;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    upstream all {
        server demo:80;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://all;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        } 
    }
}
```

This is how my docker ps -a looks like

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                     NAMES
c6530cb5e017   demo-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:49162->80/tcp, :::49162->80/tcp   poc_demo_2
48b410882a89   demo-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:49161->80/tcp, :::49161->80/tcp   poc_demo_3
858feb84c60b   demo-app   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:49160->80/tcp, :::49160->80/tcp   poc_demo_1
1a72a78ba820   nginx      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp         poc_nginx_1
```

I tried calling node endpoint and response was coming from different container every time, I want to understand how it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yaml` file likely has two services defined: `demo` and `nginx`. These names are the first important part.

Whenever you bring up these services as part of `docker compose up`, assuming you didn't go out of your way to define a complex network setup, docker is creating a separate network for them to all coexist, and, second important bit, configuring each container to be able to reach each other by their respective names.

Third important bit, in your nginx config you set your `server` as **`demo:80`**, meaning tries to reach it's backends *by resolving their hostname*, `demo`, which docker made sure resolves to the name of *however many* containers you have running the `demo` application.